# How to convert DEM with vertical DATUM DHHN2016 height EPSG:7837 to EGM96 height - EPSG:5773?

Tags: elevation, wgs84, epsg, egm96

There is a [lidar data source of digital elevation model](https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/hm/3dm_l_las/3dm_l_las/) of Germany.

1. The spec of the lidar data is:

- Horizontal CRS: EPSG 25832
- Vertical DATUM: EPSG 7837

2. I have anther DEM whose vertical datum is WGS84 Earth Gravitational Model (EGM 96) geoid.

How can I transform my DEM to make it have the same vertical datum as EPSG:7837. I don't have ground control points. Is it possible to do the transformation without GCP?

Answer (score 2):

Using gdal you can add the vertical datum with `-s_scs EPSG:25832+7837`:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:25832+7837 -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=egm96_15.gtx" input.tif output.tif
```

You can download the grid from [osgeo](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/tree/master) and copy the file to `../share/proj/` withing your gdal/qgis path.